# Stack Overflow deletes first sentence of my answers

Tags: support, filtering

Can someone tell me, why the first sentence from every answer I give is deleted? I normally start my answers with "Hey username," or "Hey username, I'll try to help you. So lets start with..." and then I begin the paragraphs.

Is it a known issue? Is something wrong with my browser? Or do you have a hint for me, how I can handle this problem? FireFox Developer Edition 39.0a2 (2015-04-19) is the one I use.

Comment: Probably an automatic filter removing noise. SO aims to be a knowledge repository, not a help site; fluff in questions and answers is extremely frowned upon.

Comment: Greetings, salutations, valedictions... Stuff like that shouldn't be included on any posts. Many users will edit these out because they are considered noise and distract from the real contents of the post.

Comment: *"how i can handle this problem?"* - stop adding noise to the start of your posts!

Comment: [help-center -> our model -> expected behavior : "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: you don't need to edit the answer in to your question... just accept @oded's answer

Comment: To state it bluntly: we don't care about users, only about posts. In that sense we are an un-social-network and do everything needed to keep it that way.

Comment: ... i can accept it in 3 minutes. And i'll delete his answer from my post. Sorry for that confusion and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Either people are editing these out, or it is getting [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/163863).

Salutations and signatures are seen as detracting from the question - which is what the site focuses on, and are removed as "noise", as things that are not relevant to what one is asking.

---

When it comes to *answers*, they are relevant to **everyone** who is experiencing the same problem as the OP, so giving a name (which can change, by the way), doesn't really help anything.

Comment: Hm okay, and after they edited that out i'm also not able to edit it in again? I of course don't want to do that, but would it be possible or not?

Comment: It is possible, but not advisable.

Comment: But i'm also not possible to edit again and enter that into it.

Comment: If you edit it back in, it will likely be edited back out. Instead, focus on the content of your post as it is the most important part.

Comment: Just to add to the second part of this answer, *"i'll try to help you"*, is "noise" because it is obvious you are trying to help since you are posting an answer. Just get to the facts, post a great answer directed at the problem instead of the user, sit back, and enjoy your upvotes :)

Comment: Thank you guys and sorry, i'm new to this. I just got about 450 rep... you have about 290k ._. so sorry for this "dumb" question. Now i'm a bit smarter and i'll reduce my answers to the absolutly essential! I love stackoverflow and the only thing i want is: Help other users and get help from users who have more experience! =)

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. It takes time to learn our idiosyncrasies, @Sithys

Comment: @Sithys Don't worry, at least you asked and took the advice serious and without getting upset (it sounds like). If you haven't been all the way through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) I would advice doing so. Reading through that completely a few times helped me tremendously when first starting out here. I still reference it from time to time.

Comment: Oded, I think the OP is experiencing the [**automatic** stripping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/163863), rather than *people editing the posts*; otherwise I'd expect to see post revisions, which isn't the case in posts like here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600116/phonegap-capture-plugin-with-navigator-device-undefined/25600343#25600343

Comment: @Matt - that's possible. Didn't consider that. Though the reasoning still applies ;)

Comment: @Matt - added to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i think that is what my postings are "affected" from. Thanks to all of you and.. fortunately the votings here doesn't affect my reputation.